# Comparing colums of multiple tables,One set of tables has prefix and have less colums than other

Tags: sql, oracle10g

Hi i need to compare the columns of one set of tables with another set of tables.Let me explain the structure.Where second set of tables is taken from first with less number of columns.

```
TABLE NAMES:
W_table_1_fact
W_tables_2_fact
.........
........
W_table_n_dim
W_table_1_dim
W_tables_2_dim
.........
........
W_table_n_dim


ABC_W_table_1_fact
ABC_W_tables_2_fact
.........
........
ABC_W_table_n_dim
ABC_W_table_1_dim
ABC_W_tables_2_dim
.........
........
ABC_W_table_n_dim
```

Now the tables with prefix ABC have their data and columns taken from original tables with exception of few missing columns and maybe some data(which don't care about for now) .I need to check if the columns we need have been loaded in the tables with prefix ABC.So I need to make a query that tells me which columns are missing can anybody please help me make a query.If you need any information please feel free to ask i will give any required information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so you want to see columns (not data) that are in the source but not the target for a whole list of tables? you can do a MINUS on USER_TAB_COLUMNS for this. eg:

```
with tables as
 (select table_name t1, 'ABC_'||table_name t2 --<--- prefixed table 2 based on tables name
    from user_tables 
   where table_name in ('W_TABLE_1_FACT', 'W_TABLES_2_FACT' ))
select t.*,
       cursor (select column_name
                  from user_tab_columns
                 where table_name = t.t1
                minus
                select column_name 
                  from user_tab_columns 
                 where table_name = t.t2) missing_columns
  from tables t
```